# Difference between hat and expected value

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Let's say I have parameter $\{\theta_1, ..., \theta_T\} \in \Omega$. I estimate $\theta_{t+1}$ to be the average of its past history. Should the notation be:
$\hat{\theta}_{t+1} = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t} \theta_i$ or $E(\theta_{t+1}) = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^{t} \theta_i$?

Comment: It is an estimator so $\hat{\theta}_{t+1}$ is better.  As an observed average you might also write $\bar{\theta}$  for the right hand side (watch out for possible index confusion) so you might say $\hat{\theta}_{t+1} = \bar{\theta}$.  Meanwhile $E\left({\theta}_{t+1}\right)$ is an expectation rather than an observed average

Comment: I see. Thanks for that